# Haskell - class vs typeclass - what is the difference

Tags: class, haskell, types

Hello Haskellers and Haskellettes,

I've been fiddling around with Haskell for quite a while but there is this concept of classes I cannot quite grasp. In the following example I have the datatype of `ExprTree`

```
data Val a = Num a | Var String deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
data ExprTree = Leaf {lab::Label, val::(Val a)=> a}
          | Node {lab::Label, fun::Fun, lBranch::ExprTree, rBranch::ExprTree}
          deriving(Eq,Ord)
```

which leads to

```
Type constructor `Val' used as a class In the definition
of data constructor `Leaf' In the data type declaration for `ExprTree'
```

i also tried

```
data ExprTree' = Leaf {lab::Label, val::Val}
         ...
```

but randomly changing type signature - neither sounds efficent nor provides enlightenment.

now as far as i know `Num a` denotes something of class `Num` but is this is no instance of a datatype - and doesn't let me compile.
So what do i have to do in order to make `ExprTree` well defined.

Thanks in advance for hints and ideas!

---

**Edit**:

1) Thanks for the fast answers!

2) I changed the `val::(Val a)=>a` to `val::Val a`

i had something similar in mind - but then the error: `Not in scope type variable a` occurs
do you have additional advice ??

Comment: Notice the answer includes the type variable `a` on the left hand side as well: `data ExprTree a = ...`

Comment: man sometimes I'm dumber than a piece of stone - thanks ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct type would be

```
data Val a = Num a | Var String deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
data ExprTree a = Leaf {lab::Label, val :: Val a}
          | Node {lab::Label, fun::Fun, lBranch::ExprTree a, rBranch::ExprTree a}
          deriving(Eq,Ord)
```

Since the type `Val` requires an additional type parameter, you need to provide one whenever you use it<sup>*</sup>.  I used a type variable, just as in the initial definition; that requires the variable to also be named as a parameter to `ExprTree`.  (The other possibilities would be to use a concrete type such as `Int` or `Maybe String`, etc., or to use an existential type; neither makes sense here.)

What you actually used was a typeclass context ("class" is just shorthand for "typeclass").  `Val` is a type, not a typeclass, so it's not legal there.

<sup>*</sup> This isn't quite true; you need a type of kind `*`.  Kinds are the types of types:  `Int` has kind `*`, `Val a` has kind `*`, `Val` has kind `* -> *`.  That is, by itself `Val` is a *type function* which requires a parameter in order to become a full type.

Comment: Technically, Val isn't even a *type*, but a *type **constructor***, or a simple type function.

Answer (score 5):

To answer the question in the title: When talking about Haskell, the word "class" is almost always used to mean "typeclass" as that's the only kind of class there is in Haskell. So there is no difference.

To answer the question in your body:

```
data ExprTree a =
    Leaf {lab::Label, val::(Val a)}
    | Node {lab::Label, fun::Fun, lBranch::(ExprTree a), rBranch::(ExprTree a)}
    deriving(Eq,Ord)
```

Writing `(Val a)=>a` makes no sense because `Val` isn't a typeclass and you can't just introduce typeclass constraints on the right hand side of a type definition (without extensions anyway - and either way it's not what you want).

Answer (score 2):

The error points to this part of the type definition:

```
val::(Val a)=> a
```

This syntax means, "for any instance `a` of the typeclass `Val`, the value of `val` is of type `a`." But then (1) `Val` isn't a typeclass and (2) the type `a` seems to come out of thin air.

What you may have intended to say is

```
data Val a = Num a | Var String
           deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
data ExprTree a = Leaf { val :: Val a }
                | Node { lBranch :: ExprTree a, rBranch :: ExprTree a }
                deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is already solved, but I see you use GHC and sometimes — especially in the beginning — Hugs error messages may be somewhat easier to read, in this case:

> Syntax error in data type declaration (unexpected `=>')

This might actually have given you a first idea where to look. Mind you that I'm not advocating Hugs over GHC here, but as a Haskell beginner I think that the former provides more helpful error messages.

Answer (score 1):

If you are coming from an OOP language, a few simple rules may help you get oriented:

1. When Haskellers speak of classes or typeclasses, that's vaguely like an interface or trait in an OOP language.
2. What appears on the LHS of data ... = ... is vaguely like an abstract superclass. You can't actually make one, but you can declare a parameter of that type.
3. What appears on the RHS of data ... = ... are vaguely like the particular subclasses.
4. When you require a parameter to be of a typeclass, that goes on the LHS of =>, as in Num t => t.

Now, none of this is strictly correct, and if you stop here, but the rough idea did help me get my footing.